# Javascript - replace expression not working

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

while executing the following code:

```
let queryStr = JSON.stringify(queryObj);
console.log(queryStr);
queryStr = queryStr.replace(/\b(gte|gt|lte|lt)\b/g, (match) => {
`$${match}`;
console.log(queryStr);
});
```

I receive the following results from 'console.log':

```
{"price{gt}":"1500"}
{"price{gt}":"1500"}
```

- This is my get query: `http://127.0.0.1:3000/products?price{gt}=1500`

Why does the replace not work?
Could you help me, please?

Comment: I cannot guess what you want to do. What is expected output? I tried to make a snippet, but you need to give us a proper object in a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code basically worked, but there were some inaccuracies. Mainly, your replace function didn't return anything, and the second log statement was in the wrong place/executed before you wanted it to be executed.

```js
const queryObj = {"price{gt}":"1500"};
const input = JSON.stringify(queryObj);
console.log("input:", input);
const queryStr = input.replace(/\b(gte|gt|lte|lt)\b/g, (match) => `$${match}`);
console.log("queryStr:", queryStr);
```